# How to create a table out of inputs from editText and selected item from spinner in Java?

Tags: java, android

I want the values to be shown in organized table. So far I have only been able to show the selected item from spinner and value from editText as text populated in lines. Here's my code:

```
 final TextInputEditText input = findViewById(R.id.editInput);

    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedCrop);
    text.setText(" ");

    final Spinner cropsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCrop);
    cropsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, crops);
    cropsSpinner.setAdapter(cropsAdapter);
    final String editInput = input.getText().toString();
    cropsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              final String editInput = input.getText().toString();
              if (!editInput.isEmpty()) {
                  final String crop = crops[position];
                  text.setText(text2 + crop + " " + editInput + "\n");
                  text2 = text.getText().toString();
              }

        }
```

How can I make it to appear in tables?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer to my question. The solution would be to use TableLayout and populate TableLayout with TableRows programmatically by getting the input from EditText and selectedItem from spinner